# Capturing data from multiple ID with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to capture and display attribute value within the same label as text.

I used this, but only work for the first id = "hit".
I imagine this is because everyone has the same name id (hit).

I want to just click on any link, display the data collected in its proper place.

That is, if I click on the first link, displayed as text: 934410
(if it works)
But if I click on the second or third link, this no longer works, because the second link should be displayed: 20201
and the third link should show: 2hello

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#link" data-href="934410" id="hit">Test 1</a><br>
<a href="#link" data-href="20201" id="hit">Test 2</a><br>
<a href="#link" data-href="2hello" id="hit">Test 3</a><br>

<script>
$("#hit").click(function() {
 capturetxt = $("#hit").attr('data-href');
 $("#hit").html(capturetxt);
});
</script>
```

I know I can do this using onclick = "myfunction ('value to be displayed');" in each `<a>`

but I do not want to use onclick `<a>` within the label, and that is why I find it hard to solve this problem.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, IDs should always be unique.

Comment: IDs must be unique. If you want some kind of mutual behavior for multiple elements, give them the same class name and use the class specifier '.hit' instead of '#hit'

Comment: Use `$("#hit").data('href');` not `$("#hit").attr('data-href');`

Comment: you can use event delegation to side-step the validity issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ids to classes. Ids should be unique. Also, you should use jQuery's `data` function and pass in `href` as the parameter.

`$('.hit')` also returns an HTML collection. To get the specific text, you need to use `$(this)`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#link" data-href="934410" class="hit">Test 1</a><br>
<a href="#link" data-href="20201" class="hit">Test 2</a><br>
<a href="#link" data-href="2hello" class="hit">Test 3</a><br>

<script>
    $(".hit").on('click', function() {
        capturetxt = $(this).data('href');
        $(this).html(capturetxt);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is also a solution to my problem.
If it works, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDs should be unique.  Non-unique IDs are not valid HTML markup.

Aside from that, you can select by the `data-href` attribute also.

```
$("[data-href]").click(function() {
    capturetxt = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $(this).html(capturetxt);
});
```

You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/b12rx1ua/

Hope that helps!